# How to trim image edge in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

Let's say I want to show a composable view with an image. Instead of an original image I would like to trim part of the image away, for  example 20% from the right edge. How would I do this? Can I use a .clip-modifier with a custom shape?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can create your own shape and clip using that shape as

```
private val cropShape = GenericShape { size: Size, layoutDirection: LayoutDirection ->
    addRect(Rect(0f, 0f, size.width * .8f, size.height))
}
```

0.8 is arbitrary number, you can customize your Rectangle as you wish

```
    Image(
        modifier = Modifier.clip(cropShape),
        painter = bitmap,
        contentDescription = null
    )
```

[image]

The one on top without clip modifier, the one at the bottom is clipped with  `Modifier.clip(cropShape)`

Answer (score 0):

You can crop it with a shape, as @Thracian suggests, but in that case the view size won't change. For example, if you put it in `Row`, you will have an unexpected padding to next item.

Instead, you can use `Modifier.layout` to actually reduce the size of the view, and clip it with `RectangleShape`, since by default Compose views are not clip to bounds.

```kotlin
Image(
    painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.my_image_1),
    contentDescription = null,
    modifier = Modifier
        .clip(RectangleShape)
        .layout { measurable, constraints ->
            val placeable = measurable.measure(constraints)
            layout(width = placeable.width * 8 / 10, height = placeable.height) {
                placeable.place(0, 0)
            }
        }
)
```